# Best way to get column totals on multiple columns with varying row sizes using MS Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sum, formula

I have hundreds of columns (fixed) and a varying number of rows depending on the data pull. I have a code which inputs a totals formula in last row plus one. This works well. But I have so many columns I need to sum. Say every column in Range H:EA needs a sum total.

I need a more efficient formula than below, but I am unsure where to turn:

```
Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 25).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R2C:R[-1]C)"
Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 26).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R2C:R[-1]C)"
Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 27).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R2C:R[-1]C)"
Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 28).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R2C:R[-1]C)"
Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 28).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R2C:R[-1]C)"
Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 29).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R2C:R[-1]C)"
Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 30).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R2C:R[-1]C)"
```

etc etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Range.Resize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize) to write the formula to multiple columns in one step:

```vb
Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 25).Resize(, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R2C:R[-1]C)"
```

---

> Say every column in Range H:EA needs a sum total

Note that the normal approach is to use `End(xlUp)` to find the last row, and you can easily build a range reference instead of using `Resize`:

```vb
With Sheet2
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    .Range("H" & Row & ":EA" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R2C:R[-1]C)"
End With
```

Comment: should be LastRow for column H qualifier (not row). Thanks BigBen. That's twice you've helped me now.